# taking off a band-aid for washing of hands for bread?

Tags: halacha, medicine, netilat-yadayim-washing, bread, chatzitzah

when one needs to wash his hands for bread, and he currently has a band-aid on his hand, to keep a cut covered to avoid infection, does he need to remove the band-aid for the washing process?

Answer (score 3):

the shulchan aruch says in 162:10

״מי שיש לו מכה בידו ודטיה עליה:
 די לו שיטול שאר היד שלא במקום הרטיה

one with a blemish covered by a bandage, it's sufficient enough to wash the rest of the hand not covered by the bandage

the magen avrohom there (which I dont have a link to) says,  it's referring to a bandage he doesn't care about it being there, additionally he points out, this only applies if it's an actual type of cut or the like, which he therefore will not come to touch it, and therefore it remains on, however if it's just covering some ailment, which he may remove the bandage and then touch the bread, he would need to wash under it (i.e. remove it).

so in your case it would make a difference as to why he's wearing the band-aid, most probably a band-aid which is not a permanent object and is therefore changed pretty often, in comparison to a bandage would need to come off when one washes,

Comment: Something you take off regularly might be more problematic, like a ring during kneading dough.

Comment: Re your last paragraph - sometimes a band aid is there to cover ointment which, in turn is treating a deep cut. If you take off the Band-Aid esp. when ointment is there, you may be risking infection, depending on the seriousness of your condition as well as your own health history. Along with asking a rav, I would coordinate with a doctor in such cases. I can't imagine there is a rule to remove a Band-Aid in such circumstances if it may make you sick(er).